# Google app engine JDO delayed data persistence

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

All,
I have a code that writes something in the data store and immediately after I make a call to retrieve the data I just wrote to data store. My 2nd call always fails! However if I make the call again it works fine and finds the data!
It's really wired! The code was working fine on 1.7.1 and I this started happening after I upgraded to 1.7.2 (can't be 100% sure as I also did a few other changes at the same time but I thought I mention it as well).
Here is my code to write the data:

```
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    pm.evictAll();
    Key userKey = KeyFactory.createKey(User.class.getSimpleName(), request.getUsername());
    try {
        User user = pm.getObjectById(User.class,userKey);
        if (!user.getPassword().equals(request.getPassword())){
            ret.setCode(ResultInfo.WRONG_PASSWORD);
        }else{
            ret.setCode(ResultInfo.FINE);
            UUID sid = UUID.randomUUID();
            ret.setCredit(user.getCredit());
            ret.setSid(sid.toString());
            ret.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            ret.setName(user.getName());
            user.setSid(sid.toString());
            user.setLastLogin(new Date());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ret.setCode(ResultInfo.USER_NOT_FOUND);
    }finally{
        pm.flush();
        pm.close();
    }
```

and this is the code to read the data:

```
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    pm.evictAll();
    try {
           User user = getUserForSession(pm, sid);
        if (user==null){
            ret.setCode(ResultInfo.SESSION_NOT_FOUND);              
        }else{
            ret.setCode(ResultInfo.FINE);
            ret.setCredit(user.getCredit());
            ret.setSid(sid.toString());
            ret.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            ret.setName(user.getName());
            if (user.getGid()!=null){
                Game game = getGameByGameId(pm, user.getGid());
                ret.populateGameResult(user,game);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ret.setCode(ResultInfo.USER_NOT_FOUND);
    } finally{
        pm.flush();
        pm.close();
    }
```

getUserForSession simply uses the following code to retrieve the user:

```
static public User getUserForSession(PersistenceManager pm,String sid){
Query q = pm.newQuery(User.class);
q.setFilter("sid == sidParam");
q.declareParameters("String sidParam");
    try {
        List<User> users = (List<User>) q.execute(sid);
        if (users.size()!=1){
            return null;
        }else{
            return users.get(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    } finally {
    }

}
```

when I debug in this function size of the list is zero on first call and is 1 on next call with exact same parameters!
As result I always get SESSION_NOT_FOUND error on the first call and on the second call I get the data I want!

The second code segment is called by Ajax so for now I've changed my code to check for error and call again! I don't like it and I want to know how I can get this resolved. Here is my Ajax code:

```
function fetchUserInfo(){
    var sid = getCookie("sid");
    var urlStr = BURL + '/game/' + sid + "/gameInfo";
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: urlStr,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
            console.debug(data);
            if (data.code == "OK"){
                try{
                    $("#client_name").html(data.name);
                    $("#client_credit").html(data.credit);
                }catch(e){
                }
            }else{
                fetchUserInfo();
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Error");
        }               
    });

    }
```

Any help/pointer is appreciated

Amir

Comment: I'm almost sure the issue is with HRD as when I'm turning it off all works fine but then again I really want to take advantage of HRD but also force the data to be ready for the call made shortly after the data is persisted.

Comment: Thanks for the nice comment dude! I know what I have, you were to tell me what I'm missing :)

Comment: What do you mean by "turn off HDR"? Are you talking about the development server? It behaves differently from the "real" datastore.

Answer (score 1):

When writing to the HRD, there is a delay between persisting data and being able to read it.

You will need to factor this into your design.

Comment: Is there any defined delay I can design around it? Are we talking about seconds? minutes?

Comment: Take a look at the "Storing Data" section of the GAE/J documentation. This will show you how to work through or around this issue and answer your delay question.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian sais you have to deal with this delay. Here's the solution:
When you first store your User instance in the data store, use the makePersistent() method, then detachCopy() to get an instance that you can put in the memcache as well. Your fetchUserInfo() will then first fetch the user from the memcache. If not found (==null) then fetch from the datastore.